# VSCode Teams Toolkit devTool/install Failure

Tags: teams-toolkit

When attempting to execute "Debug in Teams (Edge)", the lifecycle deploy fails with the message "[devToolInstall.DotnetInstallationError]: Unable to install .NET Core SDK (v3.1)."

I am using Teams Toolkit v5.2.0

I have verified that >NET Core SDK 3.1 is already installed, and is in the system path.
I have tried manually re-installing the requested .NET Core SDK (3.1).
I have tried running VSCode as adminstrator

Answer (score -1):

what project that you are working on? Is it a project created by Teams Toolkit or some other samples you downloaded from web?

Comment: It is a Toolkit generated project,. I made no changes - I simply ran it to test my environment setup, but the process fails with the devToolInstall.DotnetInstallationError error

Comment: This is NOT an answer. Please leave your question in comments, not as Answer type.